# C# Events Multiple Publishers to One Subscriber

Tags: c#, event-handling, resetevent

I have a piece of code that has two event handlers. I want these two event handlers to notify another method that there is some work to be done.

I have implemented this using a ManualResetEvent, but I am unsure if this is the best way to achieve what I want, or if there is some better way.

```
static ManualResetEvent autoEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

void begin() {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(genericHandler));
}

void OnEvent1(object sender) {
    autoEvent.Set();
}

void OnEvent2(object sender) {
    autoEvent.Set();
}

void genericHandler(object info) {
    while (true) {
        autoEvent.WaitOne();
        // do some work
    }
}
```

One of the most important questions I have is: After `autoEvent.WaitOne()`, I do some work and that work consumes time. In the meanwhile, another event is triggered, and `Set()` is called before the genericHandler gets to `WaitOne()` again. When WaitOne is reached again, will it wait for another `Set()`, or proceed if a `Set()` has been called before reaching the `WaitOne()`?

Is this the best way to implement multiple publishers and one subscriber pattern in C#? Or should I use another thing instead of the ManualResetEvent?

Note: The genericHandler is in a different thread because Event1 and Event2 have different priorities, so in the handler I check whether Event1 has pending work, before checking Event2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does indeed do what you think it does, and the race condition you describe is not a problem at all.  As per the documentation of a MRE, when it is set it will remain in the "signaled" state until it is reset by a call to `WaitOne`.

Comment: What if there are two signals while I am doing the work? Will the WaitOne know that the Set() was called twice, and not wait until another Set is called?

Comment: @BlunT No.  For that behavior you'd need a `Semaphore`, which would be a thread safe wrapper around an integer, rather than an MRE which is conceptually a wrapper around a boolean "isSignaled" value.

Comment: Ok that was exactly my fear. I had a look at Semaphore, but I thought Release was not appropriate. Maybe I am missing something. I would need some incremental method and then WaitOne() ont the handler right? What should I use to keep incrementing the semaphore count, instead of Set()?

Comment: @BlunT Read the documentation for `Sempahore`.  It describes exactly how to use it.

Comment: I am sorry I don't intend you to do the code for me, I am just unsure of how this should be achieved. I can create a semaphore with _pool = new Semaphore(0, int.maxvalue); and then each time one of the events is triggered, I would need to call release, so that the handler can proceed. The problem is that release will reset the counter to its maximum value. That is not what I want, I want an increase in the count (from 0 to 1, 1 to 2, and so on, until waitOne is called again...), which automatically decreases the counter. Maybe I am missing something there...

Comment: @BlunT Sounds like you should go read the documentation for the `Release` method.  It doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I misread the information about release, as I had already read that...I replaced the ManualResetEvent with a Semaphore and the Set() for a Release(), and everything seems to be working ok. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The question and code is presented too vaguely to offer good, specific advice. That said...

No, the use of `ManualResetEvent` is not appropriate here. Not only does it needlessly complicate the code, your code relies on a long-running thread that you have taken from the thread pool (where only short-lived tasks should be executed).

If you have a need for events to trigger the execution of some asynchronous work, then you should be using the async/await pattern, where each new unit of work is invoked via the `Task` class.

For example:

```
async void OnEvent1(object sender) {
    var workUnit = ... ; // something here that represents your unit of work
    await Task.Run(() => genericHandler(workUnit));
}

void OnEvent2(object sender) {
    var workUnit = ... ; // something here that represents your unit of work
    await Task.Run(() => genericHandler(workUnit));
}

void genericHandler(object info) {
    // do some work using info
}
```

Note that the event object and the `begin()` method are eliminated entirely.

It's not clear from your question whether each work unit is entirely independent of each other. If not, then you may also require some synchronization to protect shared data. Again, without a more specific question it's not possible to say what this would be, but most likely you'd either use the `lock` statement, or one of the `Concurrent...` collections.

Comment: I will add some more details to the question, as your answer does not seem to fit my requirements. One of the main reasons I need the events not to call the genericHandler directly is because Event1 and Event2 have different priorities. And since handling each of them takes time, I need to first check if there is pending work in one of them, hence the separate handler.

Comment: What happens if the lower-priority event happens first? Does its work get interrupted if the higher-priority event is raised? If not, then you really are just talking about synchronizing (as I mentioned in my answer). If the higher-priority event can interrupt work from the lower-priority one, how did this get implemented in the example you gave? You can still use the approach I suggest, you'll just need to include cancellation support in the worker (i.e. use `CancellationToken` for each task)